# JSRender conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jsrender

The below conditional (if) statement is returning this browser error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object 46 has no method 'replace'" in the jsrender.js file on line 463  (in Chrome and IE8)

**Update 2012-06-10---Sorry, in my original post, I'd simplified my scenario too much, and the error wasn't there.  I've updated the code (below) to more accurately represent the error I'm seeing.  If you remove the {{if 1==1}} line from this code, it runs flawlessly.  With this line intact, I get the above-mentioned error.

```
<script id="tmpl_report_entry_table_data_rows" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{if 1==1}}
    <tr class="attribute_data_row">
        <td class="entry_id attribute_data"><span>{{:ENTRY_ID}}</span></td>
        <td class="attribute_1 attribute_data hidden"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__1}}</span></td>
        <td class="attribute_2 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__2}}</span></td>
        <td class="attribute_14 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__14}}</span></td>
        <td class="attribute_13 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__13}}</span></td>
        <td class="attribute_11 attribute_date attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__11}}</span></td>
        <td class="attribute_11 attribute_date_hidden"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__11}}</span></td>
        <td class="attribute_3 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__3}}</span></td>
        <td class="attribute_4 attribute_data"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__4}}</span></td>
        <td class="attribute_5 attribute_data">
            <a href="?"><span>{{:ATTRIBUTE__5}}</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="cmd"></td>
    </tr>    
    {{/if }}
</script>

<script>
    var obj_my_data = [
        {"ENTRY_ID":79,
            "test":true,
            "ATTRIBUTE__1":"Aleutian Islands",
            "ATTRIBUTE__2":"Arrowtooth Flounder",
            "ATTRIBUTE__13":"BSAI trawl limited access",
            "ATTRIBUTE__3":"Open",
        "ATTRIBUTE__4":"TAC",
        "ATTRIBUTE__5":"",
        "ATTRIBUTE__11":",",
        "ATTRIBUTE__14":"Entire GOA"},
        {"ENTRY_ID":80,
        "test":true,
        "ATTRIBUTE__1":"Aleutian Islands",
        "ATTRIBUTE__2":"Atka Macherel",
        "ATTRIBUTE__13":"BSAI trawl limited access",
        "ATTRIBUTE__3":"Open",
        "ATTRIBUTE__4":"TAC",
        "ATTRIBUTE__5":"",
        "ATTRIBUTE__11":",",
        "ATTRIBUTE__14":"Entire GOA"}
    ];

    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("table tbody").append($("#my_template").render(obj_my_data)); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you have a specific question or are you filing a bug report?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome (19.0.1084.52): http://jsfiddle.net/yJV4y/1/ jQuery 1.7.2, jsrender v1.0pre.

Comment: The above works fine for me too.

Comment: Sorry, in my original post, I'd simplified my scenario too much, and the error wasn't there. I've updated the code above.

Comment: @BorisMoore   Did you see my update?  I think I've isolated the issue, but I still can't figure this out.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry didn't see your update.
The closing if tag has extra white space. It should be `{{/if}}`, not `{{/if }}`.